# Error in terminal: cp cannot stat –r' no such file or directory in linux

Tags: shell, unix

In Unix, I am getting the following error, when I execute the command using the shell script(.sh)

```
$ sudo cp –r /home/suri/vct.tar.gz  /usr/local/vcs
cp: cannot stat '–r': no such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Though it wont solve your issue but Do you really need `-r` option?

Comment: Need to copy a *.zip file from home folder to location /usr/local/vcs. is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 4):

Did you copy that command from some "helpful" MS Word document or somesuch? Because it turned the dash `-` into a UTF-8 hyphen, `–` (= two bytes, octal 342 200). That's not gonna work.

Note that `-r` means recursive copy, which for a simple ZIP file is useless (but will work with GNU fileutils `cp` nonetheless.)

Answer (score 0):

You copy file to directory so `cp` command expect list of files and directory. And `-r` do not make much sense when copy files. Use sample

```
sudo cp /home/suri/vct.tar.gz  /usr/local/vcs
```

Also is possible you do not use normal dash, but typographic one. In such case try to write the command by hand.